# Install local NuGet package in Rider

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, rider

Hi have a locally generated NuGet package and I want to import it in a C# project using the Rider IDE.

So far I found a topic explaining how to do that with visual studio, I guess I could do it with VS and they close and open rider but i'd like to understand how to do it. Other propositions I've found were to create my own private repository (of course, it's a no).

How can I do it with Rider ? Maybe I should use NuGet cli ?

Comment: Not sure about Rider specifically, but assuming the local directory is specified as a source in [nuget.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file) file any well-behaved nuget client should pick it up and use it. `dotnet add package packagename --source c:\directory\containing\nupkg` might also work